# aliases (sendmail) to redirect emails

Tags: email, alias, sendmail, aliases

I have read that "aliases" (etc/aliases) can be used to redirect an email to an external email address (or piping it to a script etc.)

It should normally work by putting this command in the "aliases" file:

support: myemail@hotmail.com

Afterwards you have to use the newaliases-command and thats it.

But unfortunately after doing these two steps it doesn't work at all: I don't receive any forwarded email. And there is no error message in the log files as far as I can see.

It would be great if anyone could help me to solve this problem.

Jennifer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, sendmail wasn't properly configured.
This was the problem...  :-/